# Silverlight developer runtime issues in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight

I'm having a really annoying problem with Silverlight in Visual Studio 2010. I have all silverlight SDK, toolkits etc. installed as far as I can tell, and I have SP1 for VS 2010 installed, but I still get that annoying error message when loading projects: 'You need to install the latest SIlverlight Developer runtime before opening Silverlight project xyz'.

The link in the error goes to the 32 bit version so that's no help.

I tried uninstalling all the Silverlight stuff, and re installing it again but that didn't help.

Has anyone else had this persistent issue, or know how to fix it? I've attached a pic with info in.

Thanks in advance.

[image: images of all relevant info for silverlight and VS]

Answer (score 0):

I think as per Google what I found is SP 1 needs Silverlight 5.

Try this:

- Uninstall the silverlight SKD's (you have a lot as I see in your control panel).
- try installing only SDK 5 (Silverlight 5)